# Calculate Asymptotics of Integral?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, asymptotics

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$. How do I calculate the asymptotics, as $n\rightarrow\infty$, of

$\displaystyle \int_{[0,1]^n}f\left(\frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n}\right)\text d x_1...\text d x_n$?

For starters, I'm trying to look up a definition of what it means to "calculate the asymptotics" of something, so if anyone can explain this process or has a reference I'd be appreciative.

Comment: A nice recent reference on asymptotic methods is P. D. Miller's *Applied Asymptotic Analysis*.  A classic text is N. G. de Bruijn's *Asymptotic Methods in Analysis*.

Comment: Let $\bar{x}_n = \dfrac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}n$. We then have
$$f(\bar{x}_n) = f(1/2) + (\bar{x}_n - 1/2) f'(\bar{x}_n) + \dfrac{(\bar{x}_n-1/2)^2}{2!} f''(\bar{x}_n) + \sum_{k=3}^{\infty} \dfrac{(\bar{x}_n-1/2)^k}{k!} f^{(k)}$$
Now $$\int_{[0,1]^n} (\bar{x}_n-1/2)^k dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_n = \dfrac1{n^k} \int_{[0,1]^n} \left(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n - \dfrac{n}2 \right)^k dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_n$$ and try to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,1]^n} (\bar{x}_n-1/2)^k dx_1 dx_2 \cdots dx_n = 0$.

Comment: A probabilistic interpretation: Your integral is equivalent to $\mathbb E f(\overline U_n)$ where $\overline U_n$ is the mean of $n$ iid uniform $[0,1]$ random variables. Use the strong law of large numbers and the continuity of $f$ to conclude that $f(\overline U_n) \to c$ where $c$ is a constant you should find. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, you know that $|f|$ has a maximum. Use this and dominated convergence to extract the first term in the asymptotics.

Comment: @Marvis: This is nice, but where does it say that $f$ is differentiable, much less, smooth? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Let's view this from the perspective of probability theory (which your profile indicates you are studying).*

**Hints**:

1. $[0,1]$ is compact and $f$ is continuous. What does that tell you about boundedness of $f$?
2. Note that if $U_1, U_2,\ldots,U_n$ are iid uniform random variables on $[0,1]$, then
   $$ \mathbb E f(\overline U_n) = \int_{[0,1]^n}f\left(\frac{u_1+\cdots+u_n}{n}\right)\mathrm d u_1 \cdots \mathrm d u_n$$
   where $\overline U_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n U_i$. So, we have a probabilistic interpretation of the integral in question.
3. Argue that $\overline U_n \to c$ (almost surely) for some $c \in \mathbb R$. Identify this $c$.
4. Use continuity of $f$ to conclude that $f(\overline U_n) \to f(c)$.
5. To conclude that $\mathbb E f(\overline U_n) \to a$ for some $a \in \mathbb R$ that you should identify, use hint 1 and any one of a couple different standard results that you should know about convergence of integrals (expected values!) given convergence of a sequence of functions (with appropriate properties).

Finally note that we've made no additional assumptions about smoothness of $f$ while carrying out this program.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I'm wondering how to identify $c$ in step 3 and $a$ in step 5? What can I use to obtain these?

Comment: @Chris: The strong law of large numbers and the definition of continuity.

Comment: Is $a=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Chris: Not necessarily. But, $c$ is. :-)